# How do I install xCode command line tools? How to install Xcode 9 beta along with xCode 8?

Tags: xcode, beta, xcode8

Are the tools available? I have an apple developer account and I have Xcode 9 beta downloaded which I got from https://developer.apple.com/download/.

Are Xcode 9 developer tools out?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

When you install Xcode, you'll install command line tools too. You can verify by typing `$ gcc`. If you get an error like:`clang: error: no input files`, you already **have** command line tools. But just for info, you can do `$ xcode-select --install` if you want the command line tools.

Now to use both `Xcode8` and `Xcode9 Beta` **together**, you need to do the following:

**0) Close all open Xcode projects and quit Xcode**

1) Rename your `Xcode` (8 which will be just Xcode.app in your /Applications directory) to something like `Xcode8` .

2) Type in `$ xattr -d com.apple.quarantine /Users/<your_user_name>/<the downloaded directory>/Xcode-beta.app`. Here you need to drag your xcode-beta(xcode9) to your terminal once you just type `$ xattr -d com.apple.quarantine`.  Now, move your Xcode-beta into your /Applications directory and rename it as `Xcode` .

3) Type in `$ sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode(which is 9 now).app/Contents/Developer` . If you want to switch back to 8, just type in the same command with `Xcode8.app`  in the place of `Xcode.app`.

4) Verify you're using Xcode 9 by typing `$ xcode-select -print-path`. You can see that it'll point to `Xcode.app` which actually is Xcode-beta, i.e., Xcode 9.
Xcode-beta is xcode 9.

Comment: Oh! I'm dumb. Thanks! But when I try something like `xcodebuild -version` I get `Xcode 7.3.1`. How can I fix that?

Comment: I do. Is there a way I can keep it? Or should I uninstall it and just use xcode 8?

Comment: Oh you sure can keep both of them. I'll update my answer. Check it out.

Comment: Updated. Try it. You may encounter an error. Tell me what that is. I'll help you.

Comment: Step 2) fails (with the Xcode 8 GM): I get error message: xattr: /Users/thisuser/Downloads/Xcode8GM.app: No such xattr: com.apple.quarantine".